# Extracting Scala Case Class Value

Tags: scala, class, pattern-matching, case, traits

I have the following trait in my Scala project

```
sealed trait Value
case class Float(f: Double) extends Value
case class Bool(b: Boolean) extends Value
case object Error extends Value
```

Later I have the value `lst: List[Value]`.

I am trying to get the value of the first element of the list with `lst.head.f` but I get the following error `Cannot resolve symbol f`.

From what I gathered from other stack overflow questions on a similar topic, it should be working, but it isn't.

Comment: What should `lst.head.f` produce on `lst = List(Bool(true))` or `lst = List(Error)`?

Comment: Probably you want `lst.head match { case Float(f) => f }` or `lst.head match { case x: Float => x.f }`.

Comment: What if the list is empty? what if the first value is not a **Float**?

Comment: Since you said you are new to **Scala** let me give you advice. **Scala**  IS NOT another OOP language for which you only need to learn its syntax. **Scala** IS a mix between OOP and FP, as such, you need to re-learn a lot of things, especially how to design program and how to approach problems. Things like immutability, option, higher-order functions, etc are the design patterns of functional languages. So the advice would be to get a book or find a course that guides you not only into the syntax but through the mindset of a functional programmer.

Answer (score 5):

The code needs to allow for the `lst` being empty or the first `Value` being something other than `Float`. This code will safely extract any `Double` value into an `Option`:

```
val optF: Option[Double] = lst.headOption.collect{ case Float(f) => f}
```

This will return `Some` if there was a first element in the list and it was a `Float`, otherwise it will return `None`. Use the standard `Option` operations to check for an error, or just get a value using `getOrElse`.

Comment: Can you explain what `Option` is. I'm new to Scala

Comment: Probably best to read some articles, but `Option` is a way of handling values that may or may not be there. It is a type safe alternative to using `null` or some other invalid value. An `Option` value is either `None` if it is not there, or `Some(value)` if it is there. You can use `getOrElse(default)` on an `Option` to retrieve the value if it is there, or get the default if it is not there. It is like a collection with either 0 or 1 elements, so lots of collection methods also work, like `isEmpty`.

Comment: @ZacharyElkins https://alvinalexander.com/scala/best-practice-option-some-none-pattern-scala-idioms/

Answer (score 2):

Your `lst` has the type `Value` which doesn't define the value `f`.

What if the first element in the list is of type `Bool`? It clearly doesn't define `f` too.

What's your use case here? You can either make sure that all subtypes of `Values` define `f` with

```
sealed trait Value {
   def f 
}
```

or just get the `f` if the type is `Float`

```
lst.head match {
  case Float(f) => 
    // Do something with 
    f
  case Bool(b) =>
    // Do something with 
    b
  case e: Error => 
    // Do something with the error
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It was as simple as the following:

```
val v1 = lst(0) match => {
  Float(f) => f
  Bool(b) => b
  _ => "Something else"
}
```

I was just over thinking it.

Comment: After you fix the syntax errors in the posted code, have a look at the type of your `v1` result. Not a terribly useful solution.